# Sound quality not good for ubuntu 20.04 how to turn on bluetooth?

Tags: 20.04

Are any additional packages needed to be installed to improve sound quality ? I purchased a wired earphone since I was not able to enable Bluetooth and play sound on my wireless headphones.

The sound was good when I used 14.04  16.04 ubuntu . Also tell me how to turn on bluetooth so that I can play sound via bluetooth in my wireless earphones .

I am wasting my time like anything on this query but not able to find answer's .

For wired earphones the sound quality is not good .

For wireless earphones I want to enable my Bluetooth but its not enabling and option says a dongle is required .

Please someone help me out .

Comment: What exactly is wrong with the sound quality?  Usually it works or it doesn't.  Maybe your new headphones have poor sound quality?

Comment: Does you computer have a Bluetooth radio in it? That is the first and foremost thing you need to know. If not, you will need to install one.

Comment: Sound is not clear . Not as usual . I purchased a new earphone and tested it in shop . So no problem with headphone .

Comment: I am using HP pavillion G6 notebook i5 processor @2.5 gHZ

Comment: I did a fresh install of ubuntu 20.04 LTS and facing this problem .

Comment: @Dave how to test for bluetooth radio ? I want to know more about it . any command ?

Comment: @All sound quality is perfect for ubuntu 20.04 . The problem was that I inserted my headphones jack completely inside the hole , so sound clarity was not good . I just inserted the headphone jack now half the way inside its hole , then I am getting good sound quality . Thank you all .